# Pass HTML element with attribute via an HTML element's attribute

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-translate

I have an HTML element which I annotated with an angular directive, in this case translate from [ngTranslate](http://angular-translate.github.io/). ngTranslate gives the option to interpolate values in the translation string at runtime with arbitrary angular expressions (and even a subcompile option for compiling containes directives).

Now my problem is I would like to interpolate `{{name}}` in the message `Hello {{name}}` with a custom directive `<test blah="'Robert'"></test>`. That is, in the end I expect to get the following HTML as output from the example below:

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <p translate="VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT" translate-values="{ name: '<test blah="'Test'"></test>' }" translate-compile>Hi <span>Hello Robert</span></p>
    <span>Hello Robert</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS Code:

```
var translations = {
  VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT: 'Hi, {{name}}'
};

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  // add translation table
  $translateProvider
    .translations('en', translations)
    .preferredLanguage('en');
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
}]);

app.directive('test',function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<span>Hello {{blah}}</span>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      blah: '='
    }
  };
});
```

HTML (relevant part):

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <p translate="VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT" translate-values="{ name: '<test blah="'Robert'"></test>' }" translate-compile></p>
    <test blah="'Robert'"></test>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can play with it in this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FQZS4eaZVm52sbVzQ1xb?p=preview

**The problem**: Passing an HTML element through the attribute of another HTML element results in parsing problems with `"`. I tried to escape the `"`(`\"`) of the attribute of the element that is passed in but that doesn't seem to work either. How can I pass an HTML element with attributes through the attribute of another HTML element?